# Probability digits 0-9 different 4 digit numbers

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Using the numbers $0,1,2,\dots,9$ as digits, how many four-digit numbers exist for which the following three conditions hold simultaneously:

**(1)**  all digits are different,

**(2)** two digits are even numbers, and

**(3)** two digits are odd numbers?

Recall that $0$ is an even number, and that a four-digit number by definition does not start by $0$.

Comment: If you show what you have tried perhaps someone will be able to use your work to provide hints answers. Often such answers are more useful for the OP. If there are more elegant methods of solving a problem someone may point out a better mthod of answering the question.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** The answer is $$4!\times\binom{5}{2}\times\binom{5}{2}-3!\times\binom{5}{2}\times\binom{4}{1}$$

Comment: How is that a hint?

Comment: @Eleven-Eleven, Well for me in such questions the final answer is like a hint! When I see $\binom{5}{2}$, I realize that a combination (or selection) happened, $4!$ sounds like a permutation, and that subtraction is because we use Complementation Principle.